# How to stub out the dependency in a static class?

Tags: c#, static-classes

I have a static class wherein I am reading an XML to build a dictionary.
Now this initialization is done in the static constructor.

In order to test this Initialize method, I have to somehow stub out the reading of XML logic and just give it an XDocument for testing, but not sure how can I do that.

```
 internal static class MasterMnemonicsLookup
    {

        private static Dictionary<string, StateCoverageMnemonic[]> masterMnemonics = new Dictionary<string, StateCoverageMnemonic[]>();


        private static StateCoverageMnemonic[] stateCoverageMnemonics;



        static MasterMnemonicsLookup()
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        private static void Initialize()
        {
            var resource = XDocument.Parse(GetResourceTextFile("MasterMnemonics.xml"));
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (MasterMnemonicsType));
            var model = (MasterMnemonicsType) serializer.Deserialize(resource.CreateReader());

            var stateCoverageMnemonicsList = new List<StateCoverageMnemonic>();
            foreach (var masterMnemonic in model.MasterMnemonics)
            {
                var stateCoverageMnemonicsXml = new List<StateCoverageMnemonic>();

                var excludedStates = RiskStates.None;
                StateCoverageMnemonic allStateCoverageMnemonic = null;
                foreach (var stateCoverageMnemonic in masterMnemonic.StateCoverageMnemonics)
                {
                    var state = stateCoverageMnemonic.StateCode;
                    if (!state.HasFlag(RiskStates.All))
                    {
                        excludedStates = excludedStates | state;
                        var mnemonic = stateCoverageMnemonic.Mnemonic;
                        var coverageCode = stateCoverageMnemonic.CoverageCode;
                        var stateCoverageMnemonicTemp = new StateCoverageMnemonic(state, mnemonic, coverageCode);
                        stateCoverageMnemonicsXml.Add(stateCoverageMnemonicTemp);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //// TODO: If All occurs twice should we throw an exception
                        allStateCoverageMnemonic = new StateCoverageMnemonic(state, stateCoverageMnemonic.Mnemonic, stateCoverageMnemonic.CoverageCode);
                    }
                }

                if (allStateCoverageMnemonic != null)
                {
                    stateCoverageMnemonicsXml.Add(new StateCoverageMnemonic(RiskStates.All ^ excludedStates, allStateCoverageMnemonic.Mnemonic, allStateCoverageMnemonic.CoverageCode));
                }

                stateCoverageMnemonicsList.AddRange(stateCoverageMnemonicsXml);
                masterMnemonics.Add(masterMnemonic.MasterMnemonic, stateCoverageMnemonicsXml.ToArray());
            }

            stateCoverageMnemonics = stateCoverageMnemonicsList.ToArray();
        }

        private static string GetResourceTextFile(string filename)
        {
            string result = string.Empty;

            using (Stream stream = typeof(MasterMnemonicsLookup).Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Geico.Applications.Business.CoverageApi.DomainLayer.DataLayer." + filename))
            {
                var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
                result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Using static contructors in this way is not advised, and your scenario is a good example why. You might try the singleton pattern using a public instance constructor that accepts an XDocument. (You can use internal, but this makes it harder to unit test). This is a simple form of dependency injection.

For testing, an instance of your class can simply be created by your testing framework with the test XDocument.

For your live application, a static instance of your class can be initialized and held by a container type, and the appropriate XDocument can be passed in privately (within the container).

Comment: I agree, it's better to make MasterMnemonicsLookup in to a non-static class and load the contents when the application starts or lazily and keep a reference to the instantiated MasterMnemonicsLookup instance in a container. Other than the possible exceptions that may get raised, it can be time consuming for the XmlSerializer to perform serialization the first time because it generates an assembly internally to perform the serialization. And if there are other threads that in the meantime are loading a type, their static constructors will be temporarily blocked.

Comment: I don't understand if I add an Instance constructor, how does the class is singleton?

Comment: The type itself will not be a singleton, but you can treat it as a singleton if a container type is responsible for creating the only instance of it. I'm assuming this is not a public library you are creating so the fact that it will be public and not static should not matter. This is a recommended pattern by Google: see http://googletesting.blogspot.com/2008/08/where-have-all-singletons-gone.html for example.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Darious Vaughan-Scott

But if you want to keep using the static constructor you may want to put the loading logic into a seperate class which makes it easier to test.

For example

```
      internal class MasterMnemonicsLoader
      {
        public void Load(
            XDocument resource,
            Dictionary<string, StateCoverageMnemonic[]> masterMnemonics,
            StateCoverageMnemonic[] stateCoverageMnemonics)
        {
            //Do the loading here

        }
    }
```

and in the Initialize method you can call the Load method

```
 private static void Initialize()
 {
    var resource = XDocument.Parse(GetResourceTextFile("MasterMnemonics.xml"));
    var loader = MasterMnemonicsLoader();
    loader.Load(resource, masterMnemonics, stateCoverageMnemonics);
```